# Which vscode config files to restore on new system to duplicate setup?

Tags: javascript, linux, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode on linux and backed up `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`. I copied that file to a new system and installed vscode there, but none of the extensions, etc that I had configured were installed because `settings.json` doesn't contain any information about extensions.

What's the minimum set of files that I need to restore to duplicate my vscode setup on another system? I could copy all of `~/.config/Code`, but I'd like to know what the minimum set of files I need is to get the settings and extensions back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `vscode` on `linux` you should backup the files located under `~/.vscode/extensions` in addtion to what you are currently doing (i.e, backing up `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`)

The [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) is one great extenstion which coders use much for backing up all your `vscode` settings. Give it a try!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if it is necessary also to back up `~/.config/Code/storage.json`, I see some things about keybindings in there but is that the correct file for backing up keybindings?

Comment: Ideally speaking we should back  the Settings File, Keybinding File, Launch File, Snippets Folder, VSCode Extensions and our workspace all together, Thats where the "Settings Sync" extension comes in handy.

Comment: On a Mac, you want `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code` instead of `~/.config/Code`.